# JavaScript get element by name

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Consider this function:

```
function validate()
{
  var acc = document.getElementsByName('acc').value;
  var pass = document.getElementsByName('pass').value;

  alert (acc);
}
```

And this HTML part:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" valign="top">
    <tr>
        <td class="td1">Account</td>
        <td class="td2"><input type="text" name="acc" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="td1">
        <td>Password</td>
        <td class="td2"><input type="password" name="pass" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div><button onClick="validate()" class="cupid-greenx">Login now</button></div>
```

The alert box is showing, but it shows "undefined".

Comment: If you can change it altogether, I would recommend adding a field "id" to your two input fields, and use `document.getElementById`, which returns exactly one value.

Comment: better still: `var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input')`, returns a nodelist, from which you can extract both elements like so: var pass = inputs.item('pass'). Just a tip, this can speed things up if you're dealing with a big DOM, as `getElementById` will search the entire tree each time, whereas a nodelist won't, so it's faster...

Comment: Little cute code indeed XD

Answer (score 332, accepted):

The reason you're seeing that error is because `document.getElementsByName` returns a `NodeList` of elements. And a `NodeList` of elements does not have a `.value` property.

Use this instead:

```
document.getElementsByName("acc")[0].value
```

Answer (score 54):

All Answers here seem to be outdated. Please use this now:

```js
document.querySelector("[name='acc']");
document.querySelector("[name='pass']")
```

Answer (score 37):

Note the plural in this method:

```
document.getElementsByName()
```

That returns an array of elements, so use [0] to get the first occurence, e.g.

```
document.getElementsByName()[0]
```

Comment: It's not an array, it's a NodeList :-)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine - Actually it's a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCollection) ;)

Comment: @j08691 [nope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName) :) but it can be easy to be confused :p

Comment: Whats the definition of an array and how is this different? A NodeList is just an object wrapped around an array of HTMLElements with a few convenience methods. Anyway, to put it in layman's terms for the OP, I said an array.

Comment: An array has a lot more methods than a NodeList. A NodeList takes some methods/properties from arrays such as the `length` property, but it's also missing *a lot* of methods, such as `map`, `forEach`, etc. Which explains why we need to use: `Array.prototype.forEach.call( NodeList, fn )`.

Comment: In basic terms, an array is a collection of elements, so it is not incorrect to call it an array. Its like if I were to call you a mammal rather than a human being; you are both, although human being describes you most accurately.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine - "document.getElementsByName() returns aHTMLCollection of all the elements with a given value for the name attribute."

Comment: @j08691 uh, yeah. The [french version](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/DOM/document.getElementsByName) says it returns a NodeList :o

Comment: @Ozzy: well, except an `array` in javascript is a specific kind of object, not just a concept.

Answer (score 16):

You want this:

```
function validate() {
    var acc = document.getElementsByName('acc')[0].value;
    var pass = document.getElementsByName('pass')[0].value;

    alert (acc);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for using the OP's example in your answer.

Comment: @KrisBoyd, the difference is that I'm getting the first element from the array returned by `getElementsByName`. Maybe I should've made that more clear -- feel free to edit if you like.

Comment: I was giving you a complement :) none of the higher answers form it in the same format at the OP

Answer (score 9):

Method document.getElementsByName returns an array of elements. You should select first, for example.

```
document.getElementsByName('acc')[0].value
```

Comment: It's not an array, it's a NodeList :-)

Answer (score 6):

```
document.getElementsByName("myInput")[0].value;
```

Comment: Just to be clear: this is getting an element out of a NodeList. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness so others reading this have a good idea of safety nets, especially with no guarantee to get the element you want, you could test for missing values, using null coalesce to set a default:

```
const accElements = document.getElementsByName('acc');
const accElement = accElements[0] ?? null; // Or some other value
if (!accElement) {
    // handle the problem
}
```

And use [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) when it's connected objects (and not arrays/nodes being returned):

```
const acc = document.getElementById('acc')?.value ?? null; // Or some other value
```

Also, while the `name` attribute is sometimes all that is available, do try to use `id` where possible as they have more chance of being unique. Assuming that your desired element is in results index 0 (`[0]`) is usually safe, but better to check and be sure. For a few lines of code (with some logging perhaps) you save your end users the problems of things breaking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many input you can try this:

```
<input type="text" name="unitOfAttachService">
<input type="text" name="unitOfAttachService">
<input type="text" name="unitOfAttachService">
```

this line is used to get all values of the tag input

```
let unitOfAttachService =document.getElementsByName("unitOfAttachService");
```

this is how to get it out of the list and use

```
for (let k = 0; k < unitOfAttachService .length; k++) {
  unitOfAttachService[k].value;}
```