# Access nested objects using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

relevant part in html:

```
<td id="a07" bgcolor="brown">
    <button type="button" name="blabla">
        <img name="wknight" src="img/wknight.png" height="45" />
    </button>
</td>
```

what im tring to do in javascrip:

```
var knightsource = document.getelementbyid("a07").blabla.wknight.src
```

This code in javascript is not working. I'm new to javascript.

I want to get to the `src` of the image put it in a variable and also want to be able to change the src.

Comment: show us you html code. is `blabla` and `wknight` are ids too?

Comment: relevant part in html:

<td id = "a07" bgcolor = "brown"> <button type="button" name = "blabla"><img name ="wknight" src=  "img/wknight.png" height ="45"/> <button> </td>

Comment: @adi Welcome to SO. I fixed the formatting for you. Next time please take some time to go through the little help section about formatting before asking the question :)

Comment: @adi ok , have a look at my answer too

Comment: if you have control over the html then changing img name to img id would make it a whole lot simpler, you could add the id also instead of replacing the name. `<img name="wknight" id="wknight" src="..."/>`

Answer (score 2):

Using something like the following would allow you to keep the format of your html the same, and access other instances (if they exist) by changing "a07" to the containers id.

`document.getElementById("a07").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src`

Comment: This code is interesting. Objects TD has the function getEelment..?

Comment: Those functions (getElement.. and getElements..) do not return elements like that, they return DOMNode and DOMNodeList (those names might not be correct, but the idea is). Which do have those methods and functions, which allows you to chain them. (calling a function on the result of another)

Answer (score 1):

Turn this line:

```
<img name ="wknight" src=  "img/wknight.png" height ="45"/>
```

into this:

```
<img name ="wknight" id="wknight" src=  "img/wknight.png" height ="45"/>
```

and then you can get your `wknight` like this:

```
var knightsource = document.getElementById("wknight").src
```

Id is for one and only element on the page , so you can get it directly

Comment: As this is a table cell, its possible there might be multiple instances of `wknight` so the id might need to be "a07_wknight" or something to avoid duplicates.

Comment: my function gets only the id of the table cell - only the "a07"

Comment: @adi , so try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306129/javascript-get-element-by-name

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you missed that javascript is case sensitive. Use this line instead:

```
var knightsource = document.getElementById("a07").blabla.wknight.src
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for you, assuming that your markup is always formatted the same.

CSS

```
.imgwk {
    height: 45px;
}
```

HTML

```
<table id="table01">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="a01" bgcolor="brown">
                <button type="button" name="blabla">
                    <img class="imgwk" name="wknight" src="http://thumb1.shutterstock.com/thumb_small/98550/98550,1278941506,3/stock-photo-white-chess-knight-56993335.jpg" />
                </button>
            </td>
            <td id="a02" bgcolor="brown">
                <button type="button" name="blabla">
                    <img class="imgwk" name="wknight" src="http://thumb1.shutterstock.com/thumb_small/98550/98550,1278941506,3/stock-photo-white-chess-knight-56993335.jpg" />
                </button>
            </td>
            <td id="a03" bgcolor="brown">
                <button type="button" name="blabla">
                    <img class="imgwk" name="wknight" src="http://thumb1.shutterstock.com/thumb_small/98550/98550,1278941506,3/stock-photo-white-chess-knight-56993335.jpgg" />
                </button>
            </td>
            <td id="a04" bgcolor="brown">
                <button type="button" name="blabla">
                    <img class="imgwk" name="wknight" src="http://thumb1.shutterstock.com/thumb_small/98550/98550,1278941506,3/stock-photo-white-chess-knight-56993335.jpg" />
                </button>
            </td>
            <td id="a05" bgcolor="brown">
                <button type="button" name="blabla">
                    <img class="imgwk" name="wknight" src="http://thumb1.shutterstock.com/thumb_small/98550/98550,1278941506,3/stock-photo-white-chess-knight-56993335.jpg" />
                </button>
            </td>
            <td id="a06" bgcolor="brown">
                <button type="button" name="blabla">
                    <img class="imgwk" name="wknight" src="http://thumb1.shutterstock.com/thumb_small/98550/98550,1278941506,3/stock-photo-white-chess-knight-56993335.jpgg" />
                </button>
            </td>
            <td id="a07" bgcolor="brown">
                <button type="button" name="blabla">
                    <img class="imgwk" name="wknight" src="http://thumb1.shutterstock.com/thumb_small/98550/98550,1278941506,3/stock-photo-white-chess-knight-56993335.jpg" />
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
function getImgSrc(tableID, tdId) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID),
        tds = table.getElementsByTagName("td"),
        img,
        src;

    Array.prototype.some.call(tds, function (td) {
        if (td.id === tdId) {
            img = td.getElementsByTagName("img");
            if (img && img.length) {
                src = img[0].src;
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    });

    return src;
}

function setImgSrc(tableID, tdId, src) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID),
        tds = table.getElementsByTagName("td"),
        img;

    Array.prototype.some.call(tds, function (td) {
        if (td.id === tdId) {
            img = td.getElementsByTagName("img");
            if (img && img.length) {
                img[0].src = src;
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    });

    return src;
}

alert(getImgSrc("table01", "a07"));

setImgSrc("table01", "a07", "http://img135.imageshack.us/img135/8067/daciathaliabe5.jpg"
```

);

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Y7mLM/)

Considerations:

Using IDs instead of NAMEs as an ID has to be unique whereas a NAME does not. This may or may not be relevant to your markup, depending on the situation.

Use CSS classes rather than inline styling: [Inline Styles vs Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142710/inline-styles-vs-classes)

This selection method is not the only way to get the desired result, you could also use [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) or an external library like [jquery](http://jquery.com/)