# Get <td> value from its button using php and html

Tags: javascript, php, html

If I have this:

```
<td name="id1">First</td> <button>btn1</button>
<td name="id2">Second</td> <button>btn2</button>
<td name="id3">Third</td> <button>btn3</button>
<td name="id4">Fourth</td> <button>btn4</button>
```

I want if I click (btn1) the form send to my controller and then I can have (id2)
the ids generated by database so I don't know what is the number, how can I get the number by clicking the same side button?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript get element by name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306129/javascript-get-element-by-name)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using name, use ID

```
<td id="id1">First</td> <button>btn1</button>
<td id="id2">Second</td> <button>btn2</button>
<td id="id3">Third</td> <button>btn3</button>
<td id="id4">Fourth</td> <button>btn4</button>
```

Then use JavaScript like so:

```
document.getElementById('id1').innerHTML; // this is the value
```

or

```
document.getElementById('id1').id; // this is the value
```

or

```
document.getElementById('id1').value; // this is the value
```

To make the button work:

```
<td id="id1">First</td> <button id='btn1' onclick="handleButton(this);">btn1</button>
<td id="id2">Second</td> <button  id='btn2'onclick="handleButton(this);">btn2</button>
<td id="id3">Third</td> <button  id='btn3'onclick="handleButton(this);">btn3</button>
<td id="id4">Fourth</td> <button  id='btn4'onclick="handleButton(this);">btn4</button>
```

The JavaScript function:

```
function handleButton(obj) {
    alert('You clicked: ' + obj.id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! how can I send (obj.id) to my controller?

Comment: You don't have to send the object ID. The keyword "this" references the object it is representing, and you can access any and all properties of that object.

Comment: I dont see any changes