# Can JavaScript hide an element by name tag?

Tags: jquery

I have an input that has no ID, and actually shares class with a lot of different elements that cannot be hiden, therefore the only tag that I can refer to it is the "name".

Can it be hidden with JavaScript?

`<input data-vv-as="Minimum Price" name="wil-field-name-1609703229427" type="text" class="field_field__3U_Rt" aria-required="false" aria-invalid="false">`

Comment: You'd be writing javascript to apply css but it's possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript get element by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306129/javascript-get-element-by-name)

Comment: If all you need to do is hide, then this CSS should work just fine `input[name="wil-field-name-1609703229427"] {
  display: none;
}`