# Can JavaScript function trigger only when specific HTML <element> exist eliminating the need of unique ID tags?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, element

*Unlike questions based on (unique) [id's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html/79022#79022) and [name's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306129/javascript-get-element-by-name), this targets name-less and id-less  elements!*

I would like to load the JavaScript function called `audio()` **only** when an `<audio>` element is present on the HTML page.
**If** there is such an HTML element, then there would be only 1 instance of this `<audio>` element on the entire HTML page.

At the moment I'm selecting a unique id (`audio`) which works.

I wonder however, would it be possible to omit the `id="audio"` and just let the if statement trigger on the very existence of the `<audio>` html element on the page. If yess, then what if-statement would safely trigger a positive when such an `<audio>` HTML-element exist?

JS

```
if (document.getElementById("audio") !== null){
    window.onload = audio();
}
```

HTML

```
<audio id="audio" src="/audiofile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" preload="none"></audio>
```

Comment: Use `document.querySelector('audio')` which selects the first audio element on the page. Note that you are currently passing the returned value of the `audio` function as the `onload` handler. Set it without calling it yourself!

Comment: Conditionally adding functions like this [seems like a pretty strange thing to want to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). Can you clarify why you believe this is the best solution for whatever problem you're facing?

Comment: Agree with Ram. To clarify, what you do is call `audio()`, and *whatever that returns* is then put into `window.onload`. This only makes sense if `audio()` returns a **function** object.

Comment: @ggorlen Ram and Peter B Thank you for your comments. Reasing being that when the first line of HTML (containting `<audio>`) is removed in this example  https://jsfiddle.net/c8zdfhpy/  then an error occurs: _"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'paused')"_. By adding the if statement, I thought the javascript audio(); function would run "only if" such an `<audio>` element exist on a page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript get element by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306129/javascript-get-element-by-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName("audio").length !== 0){
  window.onload = audio();
}
```

Should do the work.

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName

Comment: Excellent thank you. This solved the problem! The element got selected even without any (unique) id's!